# Javascript fadeIn fadeOut keeps refading (No JQuery!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I find JQuery really slow so I decided to create my own fadeIn and fadeOut functions so i can easily call them like jquery does. I'm halfway there as it fully works but unfortunately when I click on fadeIn it keeps refading in and when I click on fadeOut it keeps refading out.

I tried to use the display: none; and display: block styles within javascript but that only works for fading Out. It fully works now on IE6 + 7!!. The issue was inside css. If someone can help with javascript now I would be really appreciative.

here's my code:

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="fadeI">FadeIn</a>
        <a id="fadeO">FadeOut</a>
        <div id="message"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
   <style>
#fadeI, #fadeO{
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 10px;  
zoom: 1;
    }
#message{
        background: url('pictures/iphone1.png') no-repeat;
        width:90px;
        height: 158px;
        z-index: 1;}

</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        function fadeOut(id, seconds) {
            var opacity = 1;
            var interval = seconds * 10;
            var outListener = null;
            outListener = setInterval(function() {
                opacity = fadeOutInterval(opacity, id, outListener);
            } , interval);
        }

        function fadeOutInterval(opacity, id, outListener) {
        opacity = opacity - 0.1;
        setOpacity(id, opacity);
        if(opacity < 0) {
            clearInterval(outListener);
               //document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        }
        return opacity;
        }

        function fadeIn(id, seconds) {
            var opacity = 0;
            var interval = seconds * 10;
            var InListener = null;
            InListener = setInterval(function() {
                opacity = fadeInInterval(opacity, id, InListener);
            } , interval);
        }

        function fadeInInterval(opacity, id, InListener) {
            opacity = opacity + 0.1;
            setOpacity(id, opacity);    
            if(opacity > 1) {
            clearInterval(InListener);
        }   
        return opacity;
        }

        function setOpacity(id, level) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = level;
            document.getElementById(id).style.MozOpacity = level;
        document.getElementById(id).style.KhtmlOpacity = level;
            document.getElementById(id).style.filter = "alpha(opacity="
                + (level * 100) + ");";
        }

        //delay fadeOut
        setTimeout(delay, 3000);
        function delay(){
            fadeOut('message', 1)
            clearTimeout(delay,1);
            return false;
            }


        //Call functions
        var fadeI = document.getElementById('fadeI');
        var fadO = document.getElementById('fadeO');

        fadeI.onclick = function() {
            fadeIn('message', 1);
        };

        fadeO.onclick = function() {
            fadeOut('message', 1);
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You dont have to define functions in the window.onload, you can do it outside to have global access to them

Comment: I have tried that but it didn't work..

Comment: I would guess you are getting errors in `setOpacity` and your interval is never getting cleared.

Comment: I don't see any errors there though... any other suggestions/answers?

Comment: I know this won't solve your JS issue, but I'd strongly suggest you do the opacity transformation in CSS. If nothing else, you'll get a much better performance.

Comment: @Al K look the updated code... i have added also a check to prevent fading when already In or Out state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - **demo** http://so.devilmaycode.it/javascript-fadein-fadeout-keeps-refading-not-working-on-ie6-7-no-jquery/

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        var outListener = 0, InListener = 0, opacity = 1;

        function fadeOut(id, seconds) {
            if(gid(id).style.display != 'none' || gid(id).style.display == ''){
                outListener = setInterval(function() {
                    opacity -= 0.1;
                    setOpacity(id);
                    if(opacity < 0) {
                        clearInterval(outListener);
                    }
                }, seconds);
            }
        }

        function fadeIn(id, seconds) {
            if(gid(id).style.display == 'none'){
                InListener = setInterval(function() {
                    opacity += 0.1;
                    setOpacity(id);
                    if(opacity > 1) {
                        clearInterval(InListener);
                    } 
                }, seconds);
            }
        }
        function setOpacity(id) {
            document.getElementById(id).style.opacity = opacity;
            document.getElementById(id).style.MozOpacity = opacity;
            document.getElementById(id).style.KhtmlOpacity = opacity;
            document.getElementById(id).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity="'+ (opacity * 100) + '");';
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = (opacity<0) ? 'none' : 'block';
        }

        function gid(id){
            return document.getElementById(id);
        }

        var fadeI = gid('fadeI');
        var fadO = gid('fadeO');

        fadeI.onclick = function() {
            fadeIn('message', 1000);
        };

        fadeO.onclick = function() {
            fadeOut('message', 1000);
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't read my question properly. If I wanted to use JQuery I wouldn't go through all this. I find JQuery really slow. I just wanted to use pure javascript. I know how JQuery works anyway.

Comment: thanks man but it doesn't do anything.. are u sure it works? it doesnt work for me now even in chrome...

Comment: massive thanks man! only one issue left.. when i click fade out it basically hides it without fading out and then when i re-click fadein it works, and then fade out works perfectly

Comment: fixed the problem like said above

Comment: the gid function need some check to see if the element is there or not before returning it.. something like if ( element exists ) go on..

Comment: I'm also trying to extend it a bit by getting the classes as well and maybe integrating that delay function like jquery does. I know that the delay function would take ages but is there an easy way to get class names too? i tried document.getElementsByClassName(names); but didnt work

Comment: unfortunately getElementsByClassName https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName is only supported by IE9 you have to implement something like this https://code.google.com/p/getelementsbyclassname/

Comment: I've included a delay fadeout function but I've also noticed a bug on your code. If I keep clicking fast on fadein-out its glitchy and sometimes its stuck. More noticeable on IE versions as they are worse browsers.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a good idea just to keep a boolean :"isfaded" and update it as necessary.

with you IE -issue you might first want to look up if it supports html5, so take a look here: http://html5test.com/

Comment: yeah i will after lunch okay? But one further question, why don't you just use css3 to fade? It's so much easier (except of course for older browsers it's crap) http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp

Comment: big thanks man. I will wait. I know but unfortunately I have to support IE7 and sometimes even IE6 :/ I know it sucks but what can I do. It's not my decision...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @malle suggestion, try something this

```
        var isFadedIn = false;

        //Call functions
        var fadeI = document.getElementById('fadeI');
        var fadO = document.getElementById('fadeO');

        fadeI.onclick = function() {
              if(!isFadedIn){
              fadeIn('message', 1);
              isFadedIn = true;
              }    

        };

        fadeO.onclick = function() {
           if(isFadedIn){
            fadeOut('message', 1);
            isFadedIn = false;
           } 
        };
```

Comment: almost there... however now if I click on fadeout initially it doesnt do anything, when i click on fadein initially it flashes and when i re-click on fadein and fadeout it works perfectly..